# Underlining to bash prompt only when pwd changed

Tags: bash, command-prompt

I want to underline to my bash shell prompt(=PS1) only when a current directory is changed.
I tried this.

At `.bashrc` file I wrote

```
DIR_CHANGED=
function cd {
    builtin cd "$@" 
    DIR_CHANGED=1
}

function dir_ul {
    # if $DIR_CHANGED is 1, draw underline
    if [ x == x$DIR_CHANGED ]; then echo -en '\033[0;34m'; else echo -en '\033[4;34m'; fi  
    export DIR_CHANGED=''
}

export PS1='$(dir_ul)\w$(tput sgr0)$ '
```

But not worked.

How do I fix?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to say it, but I'd call that a bash bug. Here's a workaround: use PROMPT_COMMAND to
copy $DIR_CHANGED and reset it, and in `dir_ul` refer to that saved copy. Minimal changes:

```
function dir_ul {
    if [ x == x$DIR2 ]; then echo -en '\033[0;34m'; else echo -en '\033[4;34m'; fi  
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='DIR2=$DIR_CHANGED;DIR_CHANGED='
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this in your ~/.bashrc with a second shell:

```
PREV="$PWD"
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ $PREV != $PWD ]] && PS1="$(tput smul)\w$(tput rmul)$ " && PREV="$PWD" || PS1="$(tput rmul)\w$ "'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(dir_ul)` gets evaluated at the instance you set the `PS1` variable, rather than being continuously updated.